# 20 V peak on a buck converter output

Tags: dc-dc-converter, buck, spike

I noticed that an [LM5007](https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/lm5007) buck converter set to 3.3 V on startup shows a peak of 20 V for 150 ns, and then a smaller peak after 100 ns. I know that the feedback resistors have the wrong values.

Below are screenshots from the design files.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Not measured by me, try zooming in on it.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that’s real and not an EMC spike that your scope is picking up?

Comment: Please show your probe setup.

Comment: Your C45 does not have that 1R damping resistor in series with it, as shown in the LM5007 data sheet. Also, is a load connected for the measurement?

Comment: No load is connected, I already told my client to try it that way.

Comment: @electroGeek maybe it's a tantalum. Hard to say at this distance. OP: is red layer a solid ground plane?

Comment: Also show the routing from reg VIN to connector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That measurement setup is inadequate for high bandwidth measurements. Long wires are picking up noise from external fields. In this case it is probably the changing magnetic field of the (unshielded) inductor during the switching event generating that noise.

To measure the actual output voltage, try using significantly shorter wires, ideally use the ground spring to measure directly at the output capacitors:
[image]
<sub>Image borrowed from [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/136123/how-do-you-attach-an-oscilloscope-ground-spring)</sub>