HV output flyback converter voltage spikes reduction
I'm trying to reduce the voltage spikes on the output of a high voltage output (~400 VDC). This output is used to apply a stimulus on a patient to evoke a response, so the output load depends on the patient skin impedance, that usually ranges in the tens of kiloohm range. The whole system has a way to control output current, and it doesn't go to more than 100 mA (even though this value it's probably never used). The stimulation pulse duration it's in the order of hundreds of microseconds.
This is a rough schematic of the circuit as it is:

Note: I didn't design this circuit, but I was asked to improve it in some way.
I know that it lacks a voltage clamp on the primary diode, and as of today I added a 1 nF and 100 Ω clamp that seems to improve the spike problem in some way.
I also tried to add snubbers to the secondary diodes with mixed results.
These are the voltage spikes (and a ~126 kHz oscillation?) that are present on the output of the stimulator

One other thing that I can't wrap my head around is the waveform of V_ds.
Yellow is the MOSFET drain-source voltage and Blue is the gate voltage:

Of all the images and guides I found of flybacks online I've never seen something like this. I guess could be due to the low output consumption since once the main capacitor charges the current is almost zero until the stimulus is applied?
So I'm asking for your help since it's been more then a month and I'm yet to obtain a satisfying result.
I'm a biomedical engineer major with a small background in electronics so I've never studied this stuff. The only things I know are the one that I've learned in these months studying this problem, so sorry in advance if my information is not super correct.
Thanks in advance guys.
EDIT 1:
Probe setup for MOSFET waveforms:


Probe setup for output stimulation:

Not the best, I know, but this is what I can do since it's all SMD.
Also idk if I can and how to share the PCB layout, since first is a new product from my company, and also it's a seven layer PCB and idk how to fit all in one image so that in can be understood correctly.
Transformed datasheed:
The transformer is not some off the shelf one but whe have them custom made for our application, but whoever was in charge of the datasheet didn't do a good job.
Here's what I have:


Sorry that's all in italian.
Also idk the winding polarities so take the multisim schematic with a grain of salt.
EDIT 2:
I added some information on where I'm probing the MOSFET and some other information about the transformer that I managed to find asking around the company.

Welcome! Please show layout and probe setup.

A diode across primary shouldn’t be placed directly, otherwise all flyback is clamped. It should be combined with RC.

@winny Hi, I guess you mean PCB layout, right? Also for the probe setup I'm currently hooked up to the MOSFET with three short wires, since it's SMD. Not the best i know but I don't have much choice. As for the output, I placed a resistor to simulate a patient impedence and I'm hooked up across it with a probe.

Yes, PCB layout. Please show a photo of your probe setup.

@MichalPodmanický yes, that's the first thing I did, and althought it improved the spike problem, it's still not enough. I also tried to add snubbers on the secondary diodes but it's been hit or miss since I can't calculate any decent values for the resistor and the capacitor

The transformer phasing is also probably incorrect; please show waveforms around the transformer (in the simulation), as well as where and how the probes are connected in the real circuit. We also need a pinout, datasheet or other diagram for the transformer itself.

@TimWilliams Sorry but idk the transformer phasing, since the datasheet I have for it it's far from complete (thanks to whatever company we have making these -.-"). I've updated the post with what I have. And also I can't make the simulation work in any way so I just used that to give an idea of the schematic.

Way too long leads. Have a look here how to measure switching nodes: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/136123/how-do-you-attach-an-oscilloscope-ground-spring

@winny Not a concern at this time -- we don't even know where the probes are connected, and what the waveforms are supposed to be. OP: I don't know what information is left that you have available / to share, but I will explain what we are missing: you have shown how the probes are connected, but they appear to connect to arbitrary points on a PCB, which could be absolutely anything, even unrelated nodes (and the "clock" and "data" labels on the waveforms aren't helping, but I'm guessing those should be ignored as prior setup that simply hasn't been cleared -- but again, clarity matters--)...

We can't see the drive transistor(s), controller, transformer, diodes, etc., and the schematic does not show pin numbers or etc. I can't say I'm any good at Italian, but it seems plausible that partenza is "parting" (exit; start of the winding / spire) and arrivo is "arriving" (finish of winding). If that is the case, the windings seem to be on pins 3-2, 4-1 and 7-6, and should be phased respectively.

@TimWilliams The MOSFET is controlled by the FPGA present of the board, don't really know much about that, it's like a black box we are not allowed to touch sadly.
I updated the post adding the placements of the probes. And yes sorry about the "clock" and "data" labels, ppl like to use the oscilloscope behind my back and forget to reset it :/

It will never work properly with the diode directly across the primary because it will clamp the natural (and needed) flyback voltage on the primary.

Can you show Vds of the FET with a larger time scale? I assume the fast drop to zero comes from leakage inductance and it rises again later.
