Overshoot at powerline
I had a problem with a bunch of series connected electronics devices containing microcontrollers. At seemingly random times the microcontrollers in the PCBs broke. The rest of the circuit stayed perfectly fine. After hooking up the oscilloscope to the power line, I noticed some overshoot ringing at the 24V when hot plugging some of the other modules. This overshoot seemed to go through the buck converter and was also noticed at 3.3V supply line of the microcontroller. An image of the scope:

Where the top trace is the output of the 3.3V buck converter and the bottom trace the 24V supply line in AC coupling.
I tried solving this issue using both an RC snubber with values 2 Ohm and 10uF and using TVS diodes on both the 24V line and the 3.3V line. None of these solutions seem to cause significant change in the overshoot.
What else could I do to solve this issue. Since the inductance is not known/variable it is difficult to determine the exact values for the snubber. Also the pulse only seems to be 20ns wide which is very small, should an STM microcontroller break down with such a spike. Could using another buck converter help solving the issue if it is able to adjust it output voltage signal?
A picture of the setup:


How did you hot-plug them? For instance did supply connect first, then data and finally ground? That is a sure way to fry modules if some connector in between does not take care of the correct mating sequence, like for example all USB connectors.

Please show your probe setup. At 50 ns time scale, you need at the least a pigtail, preferably SMA.

The modules only have a 24V supply line, no data. The 24V an gnd are connected with a 2 pole connector when the spike happens

Please show with a photo of your probe setup.

Is the probe set into 10x or 1x mode? When you plug in a connector, that is a fast step with huge amplitude and it will make any parasitic LC components in the system ringing - including the wires between PCB and probe. You might be chasing a problem that does not exist until you measure it like that.

@Justme I think it would be hard to read much of anything in this frequency range if it were set to 1x; but still worth asking. Likewise -- is the scope configured for 1x or 10x mode?

You need much shorter wires to measure anything that fast as your scope setting. Please have a look here for proper probing technique: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/136123/how-do-you-attach-an-oscilloscope-ground-spring

Measurement issues aside, do you have any filtering at all between the 24 VDC bus and the buck converter on each card? Even modest filtering should be able to eliminate such a transient. Also, consider using a "hot plug controller" chip, which controls the power-up of a newly-plugged card, making it much less disruptive on the bus.

I do have tvs diodes and two capacitors a larger one and a smaller one, I am convinced now that the ns oscillation was purely due to the oscilloscope. But the failures still happen when hot plugged would such an ic be worth adding?

Supply transients under 100ns are most often an illusion due to loose probing.  Consider the equivalent circuit of a common-mode transient:

That's not to say such a signal isn't actually present, but notice that, in the loop between scope and PCB grounds, some CM noise VN can be imposed, which drops voltage VL across the wire lead and probe cable inductance L, which does not also drop across the probe lead (red) because the probe has a high impedance, and thus the probe reads a difference.  Put another way, there is CM-DM mode conversion, and you read interference.
(More specifically, the uncoupled inductance, the fly lead and ground clip, are the L and VL in the error equivalent circuit; total cable inductance is relevant for other effects.)
We can put numbers to this.  The inductance of free space is approx. 1.257 µH/m.  The typical inductance of wires making loops is a modest fraction of this, say 0.6 µH per meter of wire length.  You easily have 300nH in the probing loop, which at ~40MHz is 75Ω.  It doesn't take much current to drop 2V (or if the scope wasn't configured for 10x probes, 200mV) across such a reactance, and the turn-on transient of a mechanical switch can supply such transients in even shorter time scales than this.
Contact closures, or spark discharges in air, regularly place in the fractional-ns range; what you're seeing is the ring-down of various elements in the system.  For example, the PCB's capacitance to space, resonating against the probe cable inductance, and similarly for other modules connected to them.  The scope is hardly an ideal ground itself, but its loop is closed through self-capacitance in space, and the power cable / earth.  Likely your power supply has a similar arrangement.
If you are having supply transient issues, it will most likely be in the µs range -- consider the time constant of nearby capacitors and inductors.  For example, if you have 300nH supply inductance (from fly leads of comparable length to what's pictured), and a 10µF ceramic in circuit (which will probably be more like 3µF at 24V plus peak), their time constant will be more like 1.5µs (1/4 wave).  This can be diagnosed at the schematic level.

Thank you for your extended reply
