Contactor drive PCB - MCU cuts out when closing contactor occasionally
I have a PCB that I am currently supplying 12V which has control of multiple contactors (12V coils with built in economizer so a set voltage should be all that is needed). The board closes all 5 contactors at start up after checking all is ok (300ms apart to allow for max pickup current time so that the higher driving loads do not overlap).
The issue I am having is that occassionaly on startup the board closes the first contactor and immediately opens (The sound is instant I just haven't checked on a scope as I don't have the product on hand just yet!). This opening is because the MCU resets. What is weird is that it does this once and maybe a second time but then it works absolutely fine then goes through the routine and closes all 5 contactors and keeps them closed with the rest of the PCB working perfectly from then on.
I was mainly just seeing if I am doing something or thinking of something obviously wrong? Mainly as I would normally expect an issue on opening contactors, not closing.
Here is a top level overview of what the PCB does, I can share schematics if more useful?

The only issue I can see is that the diode is on the PCB and the low side of the contactor is connected to chassis GND to could the path be going though that instead of the diode? Although, as mentioned I would expect an issue with opening and not closing.
Maybe a ground loop issue as the whole PCB is on a shared GND plane that is solid on the 2 inner layers and stitched through to top and bottom as well, do I need to seperte this more?
Thanks in advance!





EDIT:
I managed to squeeze a probe in today to measure a few points. These are all captured when the contactor cuts out the MCU, luckily (Or unluckily) it was fairly repeatable.
This is the 5V supply to the MCU with my probe reference on chassis GND:

The GND of the PCB with the scope reference on chassis GND:

Here it is at a lower division to show more:

So it looks like the closing of the contactor does great some sort of interference that is seen by everything in the circuit. I am just not sure how to fix this in the board revision.
For this unit I don't have tiem for new boards so I was thinking of using ferrites around the contactor cable to see if any of there spikes are filtered out.

Were the contactors disconnected from their loads? Are the high-side switches appropriately chosen?

Hi @Andyaka, the contactors are in a sealed box so no disconnection should be possible. Difenenitely not between the reset and then the successful second attempt.
HS switches are rated for 60V 5.5A continous with much higher current peaks so probablyu the other way and overspecced to be honest!

No, did you disconnect the loads from the contactors to try that out? If not you should.

You need to figure out if this happens due to power supply brownout/ground lift, or EMI interference. The possible mitigations vary. Get one on your desk, and turn it off/on a hundred times without any loads on the contactor.

@Andyaka, Sorry, misread what you said. I can't currently get one disconnected as it is sealed for now. I have a spared board and contactor that I can cycle off unit but worried that the finidngs won't be the same as the environment and setup has changed.
If I can get in and disconnect the load and this stops this behavious what would this point to? EMI for the contactor latching the load?

If you can disconnect the loads from the contactor and it works you have isolated the problem as being likely EMI from load switching. This technique is sometimes referred to as divide and conquer i.e. split the problem in half and see which half is the most troublesome. Fix the troublesome half.

Understood. And if this is the case would this normally be helped by adding a snubber circuit to the coil driving circuit?

What's your layout situation?

@winny https://we.tl/t-AFP1BfXAjx - This is the pictures of all 4 layers and a 3D of the front face. I am thinking potentially the 4.3A could be trying to go through my GND plane back to the connector which is effecting the MCU

Please inline your layout as an image.

Hey @winny, what do you mean sorry?

Don’t link to download services. Make a screenshot of your layout and paste it as an image, inline with your text, as you have with your block diagram above.

Ah understood! I have added some, let me know if you need a clearer view of any part. Thanks!

Thanks. Nothing obvious from the layout. Do you have an oscillogram of reset/EN pin and Vcc of your MCU as the contractor is switching available?

I am going to try and get a scope probe to it tomorrow, will be tricky and there is not much access and surrounded by HV busbars. I was going to check chassis to MCU supply line, reset pin which has a pull up to VCC, GND to see if there is any and the 12V supply voltage. I don't think there is anywhere else?

Those are some pretty beefy contactors, MW switching next to uW MCU may require some careful EMC design. I'm not confident you'll learn much useful from a 'scope- they are susceptible to EMC as well. Try Andy's suggestions.

Hi @Spehro'speff'Pefhany, will do. I am just not sure how else to protect this is this is the issue. Potetnially having a seperate power ground (Maybe through a LS switch) but I have always read that splitting grounds is bad if it is all digital based circuitry?

I have added some scope images for today, I unfortunately can not get to the contactor to disconnect the load at the moment.

Thank you for sharing board design screenshots. Those are very helpful.
However, I'm not that impressed by the segmented board design, this puts components in sub-optimal placements, such as TVS diodes for contactor 3 and 1 are nowhere near the connector and basically useless.
There are also a few very long traces on the bottom. But on a four layer board this may be acceptable.
From what I can tell, there also isn't a lot a "big" capacitance to go around. Most ECU's (looks like one) need to support several milliseconds power glitching. And you've already determined that you need 300ms delay between relay activations.
Unfortunately you will need to get an unsealed board and start probing.
Even if we could tell what the problem is through our crystall ball, you can't fix it while potted.
(don't ask how I know)

Simplify the firmware, make sure it isn't a firmware bug.
Check what the mcu reports as reset source.
Check to see if you have brownout, the lack of electrolytics makes me suspicous.
Measure power supply ripple during relay activiations.
Check other switching regulators do not crash.
Validate your clocking does not fail. Try running the chip on internal clocks and test again.

And if you get really desperate:

Investigate if the fields of the relays do not cause disturbance. You can do this by switching a contactor with another relay and psu and have the wires go over/under the unit.
Another cheap check is the piezo-electric lighter test. ('click' it nearby)

This is all assuming electrical, can the shock of relay activation cause it? Hammer the table with the unit on it?
You can also take your board to a emi consultant and have their instruments try to replicate the issue. Some are very helpful and have seen many issues.

We've had an issue like this, a customer kept returning board that would boot-up in self-test failure. It's odd, we could never replicate this problem with those boards.
We've spent weeks trying to turn it on and off seeing if you could get it into this failure state. Changed firmware, added delays, made selftests slower/faster...
Eventually we visited the client, he had more than a hundred meter of cable from the 24V source to the panel with our board and a plc. This caused powerup to be very non-linear in the first few moments.
We've added a 24V isolator to the panel and the problem has been resolved ever since.

Hey, thanks for the in depth response! Split my response as I would hit the max character count if not!
Firstly I agree with the segmented comment. I dropped the ball on the contactor drive section by mistakenly going for layout aesthetics instead, I am currently modifying the board for future releases and this is one of the improvements.
As for the long bottom trace, I assumed this is always better than going up and down through layers as both middle layers are GND. Why would this be bad routing on bottom layer?

I was planning on adding an extra 220uF eCap after the input protection circuit and before the range of buck/buck-boost converters. What level would you normally expect to see? I tried to calculate based on ripple from DCDC converters datasheet but I could be missing something obvious
The boards are not potted luckily, just have tricky access without breaking the unit's wet seal.
I am going to go through and check the list you have mentioned, thank you!

I am currently updating the board so I am really desperate to find this issue. I am still not convinced it is not due to a ground loop or current return when that initial 4.3A current is pulled due to the pickup current of the contactor, I just don't know how to get around this!

Hey @Jeroen3 I have added some scope images of what I was able to get a probe to today. The MCU reports a reset due to "External Reset Pin" so I assume this spike is creating a very quick drop out in the reset line and the MCU supply is ok due to capacitiance? Thanks!

@Matt please use the little metal spring when measuring this, do not use chassis ground.

Hey @Jeroen3 what little metal spring sorry?

@Matt https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/136123/how-do-you-attach-an-oscilloscope-ground-spring

You are powering the unit with 12Volts. Does the DVM show a voltage drop when the contactor closes?  If so Add a capacitor to the input power  2200mfd/ 35 volts is good to test with. If this solves the problem, that indicates you have a power suply that has bad caps and is failing.
