Can't get rid of voltage spikes / ringing on DC-DC buck converter
I am designing a variable output voltage buck converter. A Teensy MCU generates a 3.3 V PWM signal which is the input of a MOSFET gate driver (UCC27517D), connected to a P-channel MOSFET (DMP3056L.) This MOSFET is switching a 12 V supply.  The output is filtered with a typical buck configuration of diode and LC filter. The output voltage is continuously monitored by the Teensy ADC, which can adjust the duty cycle of the PWM in order to reach a desired output voltage.

I've manufactured a PCB which includes this circuit, but unfortunately I noticed very significant voltage spikes / ringing on the rising and falling edges of the MOSFET switching.

Channel 1 (Yellow) = Output. Channel 2 (Green) = Teensy PWM
What I've noticed so far:

When I connect the probe's alligator ground clip to the tip and place it in the circuit, I can see the same spikes.
Removing the alligator clip and using a ground spring did not help much with the measurement. Still see the same spikes.
The spikes are also visible in other VCC supplies I have in my circuit, such as 3.3V and 5V, and also GND.
The magnitude of the spikes increase if I increase the distance between the the ground clip location and the probe tip location. See example below. The tip of the probe is also connected to ground, but in a far away part of the circuit.


What I've tried so far:

Reduce the length of the traces, especially the power loop close to the MOSFET and the gate driver. No change.
Replace C3 with a 1 nF capacitor to see if it helped with the higher frequency noise. It did, but only reduced the magnitude of the spikes a little.
Try some different PWM switching frequencies from 30 kHz all the way up to 500 kHz. The spikes remain.
Make sure C1 is as close as possible to U1 and C2 is as close as possible to Q1. They are.

At the moment, I'm starting to run out of ideas on how to solve this problem. Before posting this question, I checked dozens of similar topics and in many of them the conclusion was that these peaks might not actually exist, but rather be an oscilloscope measurement artifact. Since I've measured other buck circuits with the same equipment without being affected by such spikes, I'm worried about my circuit.

EDIT:
As requested: Switch node waveform. 1X probe, AC coupling. Ground clip: nearest circuit ground.

As requested: Waveform with 10X probe setting, AC coupling, ground clip connected to nearest circuit ground.

With this configuration, the spikes are still present.The waveform of the PWM signal also decreased in quality.

EDIT2:
Here is the PCB Layout. Note that the component reference numbers are different from the schematic I showed earlier. For your reference, consider the ones in green.

I kept trying to measure the circuit and managed to find a position for the oscilloscope probes where the output noise is the lowest I've found so far, in the 100 mV range. Both probes in 1X, AC coupling.

However, if I position the probe on a ground node further away from the oscillator circuit, as in the figure below, the ringing is enormous again.


EDIT3:
Here are some screenshots of the PCB area around the buck converter circuit, as requested. I removed many unrelated tracks, traces and components, but left everything related to the buck converter in their exact same place.
Below is a close up near most of the components. The diode is a little far below. In white I specified the component numbers from my first simplified schematic shown.

Here everything can be seem, including the diode.

Yes, I am aware that at this state of the board, there is no proper ground plane. On my next version, I plan on using 4 layers and keeping one exclusively for grounding, no tracks. The PCB needs to fit on a specific size enclosure, so I can't expand the board area.

Please show layout (PCB screenshots, photographs). What is the gate rise/fall time? Switch node? Also, what is the oscilloscope bandwidth?

It will be difficult to see the circuit in question on the PCB, because there are many other circuits associated with the MCU close by. On the schematic shown, I isolated it from the rest of the circuit to make it cleaner. I will try to take a picture of the PCB and point out the main components. I measured the rise/fall time of the MOSFET gate and its about 40 nano seconds. The osciloscope bandwidth is 150 MHz at 1GSa/s. Measurements were made with 150 MHz probe, AC coupling, 1X gain

Please retake your waveforms with 10x probe setting. Check the probe datasheet and specs with respect to setting.

I've added the switch node waveform. I've also added the waveform of the PWM + Output with 10X probe configs. I've also noted that the position where I put the ground clip completely changes the magnitude of the observed spikes. If I chose a ground node near the output node, the spikes are smaller. If I choose one that is far away, the spikes can go higher than 1,5 volts. Even if I probe the ground, the spikes are still there.

You should share the layout. Because I’m my experience most of the time it’s a pcb issue. Additionally as a little note. You could put a zener at the gate of the mosfet to protect it against overvoltage.

Yes, layout is absolutely critical here. The reason (without giving away much of an answer, mind, but to give keywords for further research) is, your measurement is subject to common-mode error. The stray inductance of layout causes current changes in the switching loop to "leak out" into the surroundings.

Also, just to be clear as you haven't stated an explicit question: I assume you want to get rid of this ringing? (To what margin: mV? µV? absolutely gone? merely invisible on the scope?)

Layout shared. I know the layout is not optimal. This buck regulator circuit became a little compressed between other components I already had in the circuit. As far as I knew, the trace length are acceptable. Maybe the diode is a bit too far away?

Yes, I want to get rid of the ringing. I guess I would be ok with ringing in the range of tens of mV up to one hundred mV. My main concern is that this ringing may be leaking out of the buck regulator circuit into other sensitive circuits nearby, such as ADC, frequency measurements, and more. As I mentioned, when I turn on the PWM, the switching ringing can be measured anywhere in the circuit, even GND, 3.3V, 5V and even unconnected pins.

Probe ground lead issue. See here for proper probing technique: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/136123/how-do-you-attach-an-oscilloscope-ground-spring

We need to see the layout as a screenshot in the layout software, with all the layers. Board photo doesn't help, because we can't see if the ground plane is interrupted, or if there even is one, and we can't see under the chips.

You need to identify your switching loops. That is absolutely vital to make this work. Identify the loops (draw them on paper). You will see that the discontinuous part is the input capacitor(C2) and the diode (D1), together with the output capacitor (C4). Make these loops as small as possible. In your case D1 is really not in a good place.

@winny I have tried before with this probe technique (using ground spring) and unfortunately the waveform I could see from the oscilloscope didn't change much.

@bobflux I am working on providing a screenshot of the PCB in the layout software. Just need to remove some unrelated circuits nearby to help with the visualization.

No issue if the screenshot is a bit cluttered, you can just post it as-is, since you already labeled the board picture, it'll be fine no worries

Without seeing all the layers in the layout program I can't be sure, but there is a suspect on the board picture.
I'm talking about the placement of D1/D13, which is very far away from the MOSFET and input cap, which makes the hot loop much larger than it should be.
I'm also going to bet there is a cut in the bottom layer ground pour between the diode and the MOSFET. If it's 2 layers and there is a cut, or worse if there is no ground plane but instead a copper pour with lots of tracks, as the large number of vias imply... then the hot loop current will travel in a serpentine path and turn the board into an antenna. In this case it will spray so much noise around that it's not surprising the scope probes pick it up no matter what you actually probe.
You can put the diode close to the MOSFET. I assume the vias on "C14" silkscreen marking are ground, so you can scratch off some solermask and solder the diode there. Don't care if it's crooked, what matters is that the area of the hot loop GND-C14-Q1-D1-GND should be as small as possible.
Then the bottom trace to D1 only serves as antenna so you can cut it.

In fact you could just drop the diode on top of the Q1/C2 pins and solder it there to make a test:


I know the layout is not optimal. This buck regulator circuit became a little compressed between other components I already had in the circuit.

DC-DC converter layout should be high priority. If you can't move the connectors to make some space for a good DC/DC layout, then something else has to move, for example the logo. Otherwise, well... you see what happens.
As a side note:

The huge damped sine wave ringing is absolutely normal. It's the LC circuit ringing when both the MOSFET and the diode are off. In this case, L is your inductor, and C is the parasitic capacitance of your MOSFET and diode. This is normal when a buck converter works in discontinuous mode. Frequency is not very high, and it won't radiate unless the trace to the inductor is way too long... which is the case here... but your main problem is placement of D1, not this ringing.

Thank you very much for the comprehensive answer. I have edited my post adding screenshots of the PCB layout software. Now I am proceed with the test with the diode you suggested. I'll be back soon with updates.

Updates: I've placed the diode exactly as you suggested , on top of C1/Q2 pins. Also cut the leftover antena trace. Now the results: The output ripple / ringing continues to be a little bit above 100 mV pkpk (the same I already had before on my last measurements). However, the ripple / ringing observed in other points of the circuit is noticeable lower, around 200 to 300 mV (before it was close to 700 mV or more). What other points of the circuit could need a change now? maybe the trace between the inductor and the transistor are also a bit too long?

I'd say switch to 4 layers. These days on JLCPCB, 4 layers cost is so low that even for a hobby project, it is not justified to spend many extra hours to make it fit on 2 layer to save 10€! lol Make sure to use a solid ground plane on layer 2 right below top layer. You don't need ground pour on top layer. Then you have 2 bottom layers for traces. You will have a lot more space on your board to make a much better layout (with less headaches)...

Make sure to read the "hot loop" link in the answer. Another issue is ground current in the ground plane from switching. Ideally the DC-DC input cap and the diode should connect to ground at the same spot so no square wave current is injected. The output caps should connect to ground plane as close as possible so triangle wave inductor current is also kept off the ground plane. With your current board these currents will cause different potentials along GND so every cable connected to "GND" on any connector will act as transmitting antenna.

Adjust clearance so ground plane on layer2 flows between the pads of your thru hole connectors, to avoid making long cuts into the plane. DCDC layout in a compact block prioritizing hot loops. Away from connectors if possible. If you feel extra paranoid you can add a LC filter on the input, but make sure its resonance frequency is not excited by the switching frequency. You can damp it with high ESR capacitor (aluminium...) in parallel with ceramic.

I've read the "hot loop" article and got the idea. However, as far as I could see, now with your suggested new placement of the diode, all the hot loop components seem very close together. The ground that connect those parts is not exactly the same, but is connected with a relative short path on the other side of the board.  I fear that even if I completely redesign my PCB with the ideal layout and positioning I will still see some of this ringing.

Another thing I tried was to add a 100 ohm resistor between the gate driver IC and the MOSFET gate, in order to slow down the edges a little bit. I couldn't see any improvement. Also tried adding some external lower capacitance (1 nF) caps parallel with C2 and other parallel with the DCDC output. Also didn't help.

When you mentioned the "LC filter on the input", do you mean filtering the 12V rail right next to the MOSFET?

Slowing it down will increase switching losses. Regarding caps, inductance of MLCC caps is mostly related to size and mounting (trace length, vias...) so pretty much all caps of the same physical size have the same HF performance when used as decoupling. What works is to just use more caps in parallel. Yes I mean CLC filter on the 12V rail to prevent switching noise from getting into the supply. But it should be well damped, watch out for LC resonance.

Today I was re-testing the circuit on the board and noticed that much of the switching noise I had mentioned was no longer there. I used the same oscilloscope, same probes, same settings, and I didn't add anything or remove anything from the circuit compared to the final tests I had done and commented on here (moving the diode, cutting the old track that connected it to the diode and adding a 100 ohm resistor between the gate driver and the gate of the MOSFET). The image below shows the output waveform of the DCDC converter.
There is still some switching noise / ringing, but it is within my tolerances.

This left me very puzzled, and I turned all my suspicions to the measurement itself. Perhaps it could be something to do with the positioning of the probes? Improper measurement technique?
What's more, I can no longer observe voltage peaks in measurements between different ground points in the circuit.
I wasn't able to identify the root cause of the problem, but I started to undo the modifications I made to the circuit, recapturing the waveform with each modification, to try to understand. I was able to identify two modifications that really made a difference to the circuit: the addition of the 100 ohm resistor at the gate of the MOSFET, and the reduction of the hot loop by moving the diode.
Anyway, I talked to my team and the final decision was to externalize this DC/DC converter on a separate PCB, allowing better positioning of the components and greater physical distance from other sensitive parts of the current PCB. I will follow all the valuable tips given by forum members, such as ensuring the existence of a continuous ground plane, using the minimum possible distance in the hot loop, using a resistor in the gate of the MOSFET to reduce the edge velocity, and adding additional filters.
